# Book about two kids going to the moon with an old scientist

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, space-exploration

There was a children's book I used to have which I believe was about two kids who go to space and the moon (I think it's the moon) with an old guy (maybe a grandpa or just a crazy looking scientist) they explore the moon, one page had a circular metallic spot, I can't remember if it was a mirror like material. I also remember there was an alien but not sure if the characters were aware, it might have just been a background picture. It was a hardcover book and not more than 20-25 pages. Probably from the early 90s or older

Comment: This description might match more than one book. Was the book illustrated with pictures other than the metallic spot? Do you remember what the explorers found on the Moon?

Comment: No, I was pretty young when I had it, so it's hard for me to remember. Only one page had that metallic spot, it was kind of like a mirror. I remember the old man had white hair and I believe glasses . There was one page where they were in what looked like a cave on the moon.

Comment: Were mushrooms involved?

Comment: I'm really not sure

Comment: Read the title, thought this was *Rocket Ship Galileo* -- then got here and read the quetsion.  Never mind...

Answer (score 9):

*The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet* ([Eleanor Cameron](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13374), 1954) comes to mind: two boys, one rather fussy scientist (who stays behind on Earth), and lots of mushrooms. The cover has a bright circle representing the Earth that is differently colored in different editions. But the book is considerably longer than the one you describe.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the book, it's wasn't that old, I would say it was from the early 90s.